# How I can run the Ubuntu's /bin/bash on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I don not know how I can run Ubuntu's /bin/bash on Windows?
I follow these steps:

1. Open the Windows Start menu
2. type "bash" [enter]
3. Opens a cmd.exe console
4. Running Ubuntu's /bin/bash

but I stop on step 3.
Please help me.

Comment: http://www.varunpant.com/posts/how-to-install-ubuntu-bash-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed step 0:

- upgrade to a future (not yet released) version of Windows 10 that has the "Windows Services for (Ubuntu) Linux" support

The earliest way to get access to that build outside Microsoft would be to join the Windows Insiders program and choose the "fast ring".  Pay attention to the warnings; Windows 10 prerelease builds come with some non-trivial bugs.

Comment: @Romee: see: [BASH Running in Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about)

Answer (score 0):

You open cmd by pressing Win+r and typing `cmd` in the "run".

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a software like cygwin.

And/or also get the windows 10 Ubuntu Linux support.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? You can get some limited `/bin/bash` functionality by installing [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), but you should understand that you cannot run Ubuntu (Linux) programs easily on Windows.